# Pandas functions are not showing data for all the columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn as sk

df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')    
print df.describe()
```

The above is a simple code to read a csv file and using the describe functions. The code is displaying the following output

```
       program_duration      ...            is_pass  
count      73147.000000      ...       73147.000000  
mean         128.208676      ...           0.695408
std            6.889679      ...           0.460238
min          117.000000      ...           0.000000
25%          121.000000      ...           0.000000
50%          131.000000      ...           1.000000
75%          134.000000      ...           1.000000
max          136.000000      ...           1.000000

[8 rows x 8 columns]
```

What I am really looking for is above output for all the column. This problem is not limited to describe function it's also happening for df.head(n) functions.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the maximum number of columns to `None`, as below:

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
```

Comment: Thanks.Works perfectly.But I still want to know why do I have to add an additional line of code for this? I used to print df.describe() without using the set_option and get perfect result.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the other dataframes. Could have something to do with the widths of those particular columns, or perhaps a different version of the libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the setting has less number for value of `max_columns` for display settings compared to actual number of columns in dataframe so, it may be truncating.

You can view current setting of number of columns allowed for display with following:

```
print('Max columns in display setting: ', pd.get_option('max_columns'))
```

From [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.set_option.html):

> display.max_columns : int
>
> > If max_cols is exceeded, switch to truncate view. Depending on large_repr, objects are either centrally truncated or printed as a summary view. ‘None’ value means unlimited.

So, using `pd.set_option('max_columns', None)` will allow any number of columns of pandas dataframe to display.