# Pandas dataframe only shows outer columns when printing data in console

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

Relatively new to Python and Pandas, but I've been through a lot of stack overflow and google, and couldn't find anything that adressed the same problem as I encountered. (Perhaps I'm just using the wrong key words, but I hope someone here can point me in the right direction)

I have a dataframe with 5 columns which aren't very wide. When I want to display the top of the dataframe in the console I only get the first and last row, and in the middle it will only show "..."

This happens when I:

- call the print command in the console
- call the print from a script
- use `print(df[0:5])`
- use `df.head()`

If I only print `df[0:1]`, it *does* display the middle columns.
(I'm calling if `df` in my post, but I called it `channeldf` in my code)

Examples:

```
channeldf.head()
Out[90]: 
           IDs        ...                       y2
0  "1170910_1"        ...               413915.163
1  "1170910_2"        ...         413916.485731237
2  "1170910_3"        ...         413914.945323079
3  "1170910_4"        ...         413904.985148227
4  "1170910_5"        ...         413897.477030875
[5 rows x 5 columns]

channeldf[0:5]
Out[92]: 
           IDs        ...                       y2
0  "1170910_1"        ...               413915.163
1  "1170910_2"        ...         413916.485731237
2  "1170910_3"        ...         413914.945323079
3  "1170910_4"        ...         413904.985148227
4  "1170910_5"        ...         413897.477030875
[5 rows x 5 columns]

channeldf[0:1]
Out[91]: 
           IDs          x1         y1          x2          y2
0  "1170910_1"  144923.193  413914.78  144919.756  413915.163
```

I found another question which showed how to adjust the desired width for Pandas, but that did not affect my problem. I tried making it really narrow and afterwards really wide:

```
pd.set_option('display.width',100)
print(channeldf.iloc[1:2,:])
           IDs          x1        ...                       x2                y2
1  "1170910_2"  144919.756        ...         144915.931907037  413916.485731237
[1 rows x 5 columns]
print(channeldf.iloc[0:1,:])
           IDs          x1         y1          x2          y2
0  "1170910_1"  144923.193  413914.78  144919.756  413915.163
print(channeldf.iloc[1:3,:])
           IDs        ...                       y2
1  "1170910_2"        ...         413916.485731237
2  "1170910_3"        ...         413914.945323079
[2 rows x 5 columns]
pd.set_option('display.width',1000)
print(channeldf.iloc[1:2,:])
           IDs          x1        ...                       x2                y2
1  "1170910_2"  144919.756        ...         144915.931907037  413916.485731237
[1 rows x 5 columns]
print(channeldf.iloc[1:3,:])
           IDs        ...                       y2
1  "1170910_2"        ...         413916.485731237
2  "1170910_3"        ...         413914.945323079
```

My screen is plenty wider than this; even the widest output in my example is just 60% of the available width. I'm having a trouble finding a good data snippet, but the columns are IDs, x1, y1, x2, y2 and the last 4 contain coordinates with an almost constant amount of digits. The first row has 2 or 3 digits, while all other rows have 9 digits.

I hope someone can give a solution or point me in the right direction. If there is anything I can clear up; I will gladly do so (but please give me some instructions in how to get there)

Comment: Did you try pandas options display.max_columns to specify column number or none?  Your Q may duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50885560/pandas-functions-are-not-showing-data-for-all-the-columns/50889097#50889097

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas does a lot of formatting/collapsing of output for the display, which is an essential feature for working with large datasets.

A good reproducible example of this phenomenon is in the python interpreter (Jupyter and other environments may do additional things for you):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'user': ['Bob', 'Jane', 'Alice', 'Doug'],'education':['hs diploma', 'advanced degree', 'four year degree', 'middle school'], 'income': [40000, 50000, 42000,20000]})
```

Look at the DataFrame

```
df
          education  income   user
0        hs diploma   40000    Bob
1   advanced degree   50000   Jane
2  four year degree   42000  Alice
3     middle school   20000   Doug
```

Display only the two outer columns

```
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 2)
df
          education  ...     user
0        hs diploma  ...      Bob
1   advanced degree  ...     Jane
2  four year degree  ...    Alice
3     middle school  ...     Doug

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Note the output df dimensions:  3 columns, with the middle one collapsed.

```
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", 0)
```

Surprisingly prints all, as does a better value of None.

Dumping your DataFrame to a CSV and loading with a spreadsheet editor is sometimes a good way to present your resultant data.

Comment: Thanks! That cleared things up for me. I tried doing `pd.set_option("display.max_columns",5)` and that did make Pandas show more columns (although Pandas still decided to put the last column on a new line in the console) But it answered my question, so thanks!

Comment: Yes, it will wrap columns if too many columns are selected for display which would cause messy wrapping of lines on the display.